# SBT: path to the target directory for a partial input of an input task

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to define my custom input task for SBT. This task should run some app and pass into it a path to the target directory as parameter. Also the app should be able to get additional dynamic params from console. The task should look like this:

```
Tasks.generate := (runMain in Test).partialInput(s" MyApp generate ${target.value}").evaluated
```

However i get an error with reference to `${target.value}`:

> Illegal dynamic dependency

If i change code on the next one:

```
Tasks.generate := Def.inputTaskDyn((runMain in Test).toTask(s" MyApp generate ${target.value}")).evaluated
```

It passes parameter as expected, but it's not input task anymore and sbt doesn't allow to pass additional parameters on task call.

So how can i solve the issue with the dynamic dependency? Eventually i should get a call that converts a call of `test:runMain MyApp generate $path_to_target $1 $2....` to `generate $1 $2....`.

Thanks.

Comment: i found a way to solve the issue with `sbt-buildinfo` plugin passing `target` path straight into the app. Anyway for me it's interesting how to deal with tasks.